# I have multiple <h2> tags but I want to add CSS rule to one specific tag how do I do this?

Tags: html, css

I have multiple h2 tags but I want to add CSS rule to one specific tag how do I do this? I want to add a CSS rule to the last paragraph and h2 tag the very bottom one.

here is my HTML

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Months of the Year</h1>
    <p>Did you know that the word "month" comes from the word "moon"?  That's because a month is based on how long it takes the moon to go through a full cycle.  Every year has twelve months, and each one has its own name with a special meaning.</p>
    <h2>January</h2>
    <p>January is the first month and has 31 days.  It is named after the Roman god Janus, who was the god of beginnings.  That makes a lot of sense, because that's how we begin every year.<p>
    <h2>February</h2>
    <p>February is the second month, but the first hardest to spell.  Why the extra 'r', FebRuary??  Another comfusing thing about February is that it sometimes has 28 days and sometimes 29.  It means "purification" in Latin.</p>
    <h2>March</h2>
    <p>March is named after Mars, the god of war.  That may seem random, but a long time ago, this was about the time of year when the Romans would start getting ready for war, since no one was supposed to go to war in the winter.</p>
    <h2>April</h2>
    <p>April is a mystery month, because it's not clear where the name came from.  It might be named after a goddess, but it also just might mean "opening" because spring is when all the flowers start to open up.  It used to have 29 days, but then Julius Caesar added one, so it has 30.</p>
    <h2>May</h2>
    <p>May is named after Maia, the goddess of growing plants, and lots of people think about growing flowers in May.  One fun fact about May is that it never starts on the same day or ends on the same day as any other month in a particular year.</p>
    <h2>June</h2>
    <p>June is named after Juno, the goddess of marriage.  So many people have their weddings in June.  There's also a bug called a june bug that starts crawling up from the ground around June.</p>
    <h2>July</h2>
    <p>July is named after Julius Caesar.  The Roman Senate named it after him because he was such a great general and he was born then.   Before that, it was named Quintilis, becauase it used to be the fifth month of the year.</p>
    <h2>August</h2>
    <p>August was also named after a famous general, Augustus.  He took this month because it was when he was most victorious in battle.  Before that, it was named Sextilis because it was the sixth month.</p>
    <h2>September</h2>
    <p>September is the first of the modern months that is named after numbers.  Sept means "seven" and it used to be the seventh month of the year, before January and February existed.</p>
    <h2>October</h2>
    <p>Now the month names start to get boring.  October just means 'eight', to follow after September.  One interesting fact is that there was just a space with no months where January and February used to be.</p>
    <h2>November</h2>
    <p>November means 'nine', even though it is the 11th month.  A random fact because these month names are getting boring is that the Roman week was eight days long.  There were 38 weeks in year, but that didn't include the space that later became January and February.</p>
    <h2>December</h2>
    <p>December is the last month.  It means 10.  It used to be that the Romans had ten months in every year, so I guess they were onto the metric system a long time ago, except it doesn't actually work because the moon actually has twelve cycles every year.</p>
    
    <h2> my favorite month</h2>
    
    <p> my favorite month is january, because that is when usually where i live gets the most snow, and i love the snow especially when there is three feet of snow, my favorite thing to do is jump off of trees or fences and land in the snow. most of my friends think im crazy for jumping into the snow without a jacket on. </p>
    
  </body>
</html>`
```

I have tried doing a <h2.1> to try to make a specific tag reference to edit in my css.

Comment: Use CSS classes or IDs

Comment: You could add an `id` attribute, e.g. `<h2 id="myH2">`, then add a CSS rule using the id selector e.g. `#myH2 { color: red; }`

Answer (score 1):

Either assign the elements you want to select a class or ID, or use `:last-of-type`:

```css
h2:last-of-type,
p:last-of-type {
  color: Red;
}
```

```html
<h1>Months of the Year</h1>
<p>Did you know that the word "month" comes from the word "moon"? That's because a month is based on how long it takes the moon to go through a full cycle. Every year has twelve months, and each one has its own name with a special meaning.</p>
<h2>January</h2>
<p>January is the first month and has 31 days. It is named after the Roman god Janus, who was the god of beginnings. That makes a lot of sense, because that's how we begin every year.
  <p>
    <h2>February</h2>
    <p>February is the second month, but the first hardest to spell. Why the extra 'r', FebRuary?? Another comfusing thing about February is that it sometimes has 28 days and sometimes 29. It means "purification" in Latin.</p>
    <h2>March</h2>
    <p>March is named after Mars, the god of war. That may seem random, but a long time ago, this was about the time of year when the Romans would start getting ready for war, since no one was supposed to go to war in the winter.</p>
    <h2>April</h2>
    <p>April is a mystery month, because it's not clear where the name came from. It might be named after a goddess, but it also just might mean "opening" because spring is when all the flowers start to open up. It used to have 29 days, but then Julius Caesar
      added one, so it has 30.</p>
    <h2>May</h2>
    <p>May is named after Maia, the goddess of growing plants, and lots of people think about growing flowers in May. One fun fact about May is that it never starts on the same day or ends on the same day as any other month in a particular year.</p>
    <h2>June</h2>
    <p>June is named after Juno, the goddess of marriage. So many people have their weddings in June. There's also a bug called a june bug that starts crawling up from the ground around June.</p>
    <h2>July</h2>
    <p>July is named after Julius Caesar. The Roman Senate named it after him because he was such a great general and he was born then. Before that, it was named Quintilis, becauase it used to be the fifth month of the year.</p>
    <h2>August</h2>
    <p>August was also named after a famous general, Augustus. He took this month because it was when he was most victorious in battle. Before that, it was named Sextilis because it was the sixth month.</p>
    <h2>September</h2>
    <p>September is the first of the modern months that is named after numbers. Sept means "seven" and it used to be the seventh month of the year, before January and February existed.</p>
    <h2>October</h2>
    <p>Now the month names start to get boring. October just means 'eight', to follow after September. One interesting fact is that there was just a space with no months where January and February used to be.</p>
    <h2>November</h2>
    <p>November means 'nine', even though it is the 11th month. A random fact because these month names are getting boring is that the Roman week was eight days long. There were 38 weeks in year, but that didn't include the space that later became January
      and February.</p>
    <h2>December</h2>
    <p>December is the last month. It means 10. It used to be that the Romans had ten months in every year, so I guess they were onto the metric system a long time ago, except it doesn't actually work because the moon actually has twelve cycles every year.</p>
    <h2> my favorite month</h2>
    <p> my favorite month is january, because that is when usually where i live gets the most snow, and i love the snow especially when there is three feet of snow, my favorite thing to do is jump off of trees or fences and land in the snow. most of my friends
      think im crazy for jumping into the snow without a jacket on. </p>
```